# How flink read 4mc data from HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, apache-flink, flink-streaming

There are 4mc data on HDFS. When I use Flink 
env.readTextFile("hdfs://127.0.0.1:8020/search_logs/4mc")

It can not know the compressed format, so does Flink have the related API to implement to handle this kind of compressed format data?

Thanks.

Comment: readTextFile if for plain text files. Your files being compressed, you need to read binary files. I don't think there's an off the shelf solution for 4mc file in flink. But you can implement your own FileInputFormat and use the readFile function